# Get products with condition 'new' in Prestashop cart

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I get the products in the cart like this:

```
$cart_products = $this->context->cart->getProducts();
```

And I want to filter them in order to show only the products with condition 'new' so I do:

```
foreach ($cart_products as $cart_product) {
          if ($cart_product->condition == 'new')
                .....
         }
```

It doesn't work. The page gets blocked and I cannot click in any part of this and also I cant move scroll down or up.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: You use cart_product in the foreach, and products in the if statement. Is this correct or an error?

Comment: It was a mistake. I have changed it but the result is the sames as previous.

Comment: cart->getProducts() returns as array and not as object. try $cart_product['condition'] == 'new'

Comment: thanks for  your help. The page cannot be blocked but is not enter inside the condition in a product that has condition set to 'new'.'New' is a enum, maybe the compare operator is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `condition` field is not contained in the array retrieved by the method `getProducts` of `Cart` class.

Before you can use the `condition` field you should edit or override the `getProducts` method in the `Cart` class and add the "p.`condition`" in the SQL query, like this:

```
// Build SELECT
$sql->select('cp.`id_product_attribute`, cp.`id_product`, cp.`quantity` AS cart_quantity, cp.id_shop, pl.`name`, p.`is_virtual`,
                    pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, p.`condition`, product_shop.`id_category_default`, p.`id_supplier`,
                    p.`id_manufacturer`, product_shop.`on_sale`, product_shop.`ecotax`, product_shop.`additional_shipping_cost`,
                    product_shop.`available_for_order`, product_shop.`price`, product_shop.`active`, product_shop.`unity`, product_shop.`unit_price_ratio`,
                    stock.`quantity` AS quantity_available, p.`width`, p.`height`, p.`depth`, stock.`out_of_stock`, p.`weight`,
                    p.`date_add`, p.`date_upd`, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, pl.`link_rewrite`, cl.`link_rewrite` AS category,
                    CONCAT(LPAD(cp.`id_product`, 10, 0), LPAD(IFNULL(cp.`id_product_attribute`, 0), 10, 0), IFNULL(cp.`id_address_delivery`, 0)) AS unique_id, cp.id_address_delivery,
                    product_shop.advanced_stock_management, ps.product_supplier_reference supplier_reference');
```

Then as sayd @sadlyblue, you can use the `condition` field and show only the `new` products.